# liblinear rebuild: binaries freeze

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, liblinear

I have been trying to rebuild the windows binaries for liblinear following the instructions in the Readme, using visual c++ and nmake. I need to rebuild because I need the SVM probability outputs. I modified the check_probability_model method in linear.cpp as suggested in the FAQ (https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/FAQ.html#training_and_prediction). The build succeeds without errors but when I execute one of the binaries train.exe or predict.exe, they freeze/hang with no output. This happens also with the unmodified code. The included binaries in the zip file run fine.

Anyone got an idea what might cause this?

I have Visual Studio 2015 Community installed with visual c++ compiler. I used the 64 bit settings in the makefile.